# Data refresh not working

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

Hey friends I want to refresh my database after checking the access token is working or not I want to delete the Facebook expire access token without deleting the working access token but my this script delete my all user access token and I don't know why I am new in PHP

```
<body>

<div id="wrap" class="boxed">
<center>
<br><br>
<div class="bannerX" style="width: 600px;">
<div class="logo">
<section class="logo">
<img src="logo-new.png">
</section>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<?php
include'config.php';
$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM token_all");
$thispage = $PHP_SELF;
$num = mysql_num_rows($items);
$per_page = 300;
$start = @$_GET['start'];
if(empty($start)) $start = 000;
?>


<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
?>







<center>
<?php
$i = "0";
if($start+$per_page<$num){
?>
[<a href="<?php print("$thispage?start=".max(0,$start+$per_page)); ?>">Next Like</a>]
<?php
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM token_all  LIMIT $start,$per_page");
if($result){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$token = $row[token];

$userData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token.'&fields=name,id'),true);print($userData[name]).'<br/>';
if(!$userData[name]){
$i++;
mysql_query("
DELETE FROM
token_all
WHERE
token='" . mysql_real_escape_string($token) . "'
");
}
}
}
echo $i;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: That script are not deleting anything.

Comment: Are you suree @wizkid because Previous time when I try ......my all database got deleted and I don't want to take risk....so be sure plz

Comment: Frankerz I only want to refresh my database with working token and I want to delete non working Facebook access token

Comment: Can you plz show me example